# Correct way to work with two instances of Option together

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-option

When I have one `Option[T]` instance it is quite easy to perform any operation on `T` using monadic operations such as `map()` and `flatMap()`. This way I don't have to do checks to see whether it is defined or empty, and chain operations together to ultimately get an `Option[R]` for the result `R`.

My difficulty is whether there is a similar elegant way to perform functions on two `Option[T]` instances.

Lets take a simple example where I have two vals, `x` and `y` of type `Option[Int]`. And I want to get the maximum of them if they are both defined, or the one that is defined if only one is defined, and `None` if none are defined.

How would one write this elegantly without involving lots of `isDefined` checks inside the `map()` of the first `Option`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
def optMax(op1:Option[Int], op2: Option[Int]) = op1 ++ op2 match {    
  case Nil => None  
  case list => list.max
}
```

Or one much better:

```
def f(vars: Option[Int]*) = (for( vs <- vars) yield vs).max
```

@jwvh,thanks for a good improvement:

```
def f(vars: Option[Int]*) = vars.max
```

Comment: The order of the pattern matching needs to be reversed, i.e. `Nil` should be matched first. You should also return `Some(list.max)` instead of `list.max` to ensure the return type of the method is `Option[Int]`.

Comment: Second one is awesome!

Comment: @Nyavro, thanks, I had to look at the documentation to find it )

Comment: Wow the second one is elegant.

Comment: Nicely done, but the `for` comprehension is so simple it's really not needed: `vars.map(x=>x).max`

Comment: Looks like I'm missing something: `for(v <- List(Some(1), Some(2))) yield v
//=> List[Some[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2))`, how can you `max` it?

Comment: Also do you realize that the return type of `optMax` is `Any`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz, I found it [here][1], and yes the first example is not the best )


  [1]: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L336

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you'll want to do something if *both* values are defined.
In that case, you could use a for-comprehension:

```
val aOpt: Option[Int] = getIntOpt
val bOpt: Option[Int] = getIntOpt

val maxOpt: Option[Int] = 
    for {
        a <- aOpt
        b <- bOpt
    } yield max(a, b)
```

Now, the problem you described is not as common. You want to do something if both values are defined, but you also want to retrieve the value of an option if only one of them is defined.

I would just use the for-comprehension above, and then chain two calls to `orElse` to provide alternative values if `maxOpt` turns out to be `None`.

```
maxOpt orElse aOpt orElse bOpt
```

[`orElse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@orElse[B%3E:A](alternative:=%3EOption[B]):Option[B])'s signature:

```
def orElse[B >: A](alternative: ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how would `maxOpt` work if `b` or `a` do not exist? Would it just yield `None`? In my case I have this situation quite common (thats why I wanted to find an elegant solution) because I often have to choose between two items, which possibly are not available both (in which case I take only the available one).

Comment: @jbx yeah, `maxOpt` would be None if either input is not defined. The compiler actually translates the for comprehension to `aOpt.flatMap { a => bOpt.map { b => max(a, b) } }`. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes it does. In fact I think I prefer it for my purposes, it is more clear to me. So wouldn't this make it complete? `aOpt.flatMap( a => bOpt.map( b => Math.max(a, b))).orElse(bOpt)`

Comment: @jbx no, that's not enough. If `aOpt = Some(1)` and `bOpt = None`, then your expression could be reduced to `Some(1).flatMap { _ => None } orElse None`, which would be None

Answer (score 2):

Here's another fwiw:

```
import scala.util.Try
def maxOpt (a:Option[Int]*)= Try(a.flatten.max).toOption
```

It works with n arguments (including zero arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching would allow something easy to grasp, but that might not be the most elegant way:

```
def maxOpt[T](optA: Option[T], optB: Option[T])(implicit f: (T, T) => T): Option[T] = (optA, optB) match {
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(f(a, b))
    case (None, Some(b)) => Some(b)
    case (Some(a), None) => Some(a)
    case (None, None) => None
}
```

You end up with something like:

```
scala> maxOpt(Some(1), None)(Math.max)
res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Once you have that building, block, you can use it inside for-comp or monadic operations.

Comment: Thanks. I guess to make it generic its better if the function is not implicit, and not assume its just `max` which is what I am looking for really.

Comment: Exactly, it can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

To get maxOpt, you can also use an applicative, which using Scalaz would look like (aOpt |@| bOpt) { max(_, _) } & then chain orElses as @dcastro suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you expect `Some[Int]|None` as a result, not `Int|None` (otherwise return type has to be `Any`):

```
  def maxOption(opts: Option[Int]*) = {
    val flattened = opts.flatten
    flattened.headOption.map { _ => flattened.max }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Scala already gives you this ability more or less directly.

```
scala> import Ordering.Implicits._
import Ordering.Implicits._

scala> val (a,b,n:Option[Int]) = (Option(4), Option(9), None)
a: Option[Int] = Some(4)
b: Option[Int] = Some(9)
n: Option[Int] = None

scala> a max b
res60: Option[Int] = Some(9)

scala> a max n
res61: Option[Int] = Some(4)

scala> n max b
res62: Option[Int] = Some(9)

scala> n max n
res63: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: Max was just an example. The question was not specifically about max. It is about having any possible function `(T, T) => T`  applied converted to `(Option[T], Option[T]) => Option[T]` where if any one of the arguments is `None` the other is returned, and if both are `None`, then `None` is returned. If both are not `None` then some function is applied.

Answer (score 1):

A Haskell-ish take on this question is to observe that the following operations:

```
max, min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
max a b = if a < b then b else a
min a b = if a < b then a else b
```

...are **associative**:

```
max a (max b c) == max (max a b) c
min a (min b c) == min (min a b) c
```

As such, any type `Ord a => a` together with either of these operations is a **semigroup**, a concept for which reusable abstractions can be built.

And you're dealing with `Maybe` (Haskell for "option"), which adds a generic "neutral" element to the base `a` type (you want `max Nothing x == x` to hold as a law).  This takes you into **monoids**, which are a subtype of semigroups.

The [Haskell `semigroups` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups) provides a `Semigroup` type class and two wrapper types, [`Max`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.0.1/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Max) and [`Min`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.0.1/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Min), that generically implement the corresponding behaviors.

Since we're dealing with `Maybe`, in terms of that library the type that captures the semantics you want is `Option (Max a)`—a monoid that has the same binary operation as the `Max` semigroup, and uses `Nothing` as the identity element.  So then the function simply becomes:

```
maxOpt :: Ord a => Option (Max a) -> Option (Max a) -> Option (Max a)
maxOpt a b = a <> b
```

...which since it's just the `<>` operator for `Option (Max a)` is not worth writing.  You also gain all the other utility functions and classes that work on `Semigroup` and `Monoid`, so for example to find the maximum element of a `[Option (Max a)]` you'd just use [the `mconcat` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.0.1/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#v:mconcat).

The scalaz library comes with a [`Semigroup`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/stable/7.0.4/doc/#scalaz.Semigroup) and a [`Monoid`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/stable/7.0.4/doc/index.html#scalaz.Monoid) trait, as well as [`Max`, `Min`, `MaxVal` and `MinVal` tags](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/stable/7.0.4/doc/#scalaz.Tags$) that implement those traits, so in fact the stuff that I've demonstrated here in Haskell exists in scalaz as well.